# Storing instances in a field

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

First off, I'm sure this question is trivial for anyone that has ANY amount of experience with Objectify- however, unfortunately I don't.

Say I have a POJO named University.  One of its fields is a list of Professors (where Professors is also POJO).  What is the difference between:

```
    private List<Professor> professors;
    private List<Ref<Professor>> professors;
```

Say, I want write "abcUni" to the datastore with "professorX" and "professorY" as the professors.

Later, I load abcUni.  Will the professorX and professorY instances also be loaded when I load abcUni?   Or do I need to represent the list as `private List<Ref<Professor>> professors2;` and then directly access each instance in the datastore with the corresponding key?

Answer (score 0):

Since I imagine the list of Professors are not a unique list for any University entity you have, but a collection of entities shared among the universities and that can be updated, modified and have those changes reflected in all the universities entities, you simply CANNOT use your first-line approach.

Basically it says to objectify to store a list of professors that is unique to any of your universities. If a professor change in a university, no change is reflected in other universities with the same professor. And this is a mess.

With your second line, you're acutally referring all the datastore-shared Professor Entities by their keys, and this is the correct way to go (you're storing with any University entity all the keys to the Professor entities that are relative to that university).

About the loading: when you retrieve Univerisity object from the datastore, you retrieve with it also all the professors' keys, but only them (not the entire POJOs).

```
University fetchedUni = ofy().load().key(univKey).now();
//you have fetched the uni object from datastore, with a list of Professor objects keys
```

Then, you can use objectify get method to actually access the datastore to fetch the objects corresponding to the Ref keys you have in your university object:

```
List<Professor> profs = fetchedUni.professors.get();
//now you have fetched the entire POJOs list
```

If, for any reason (optimization, economy, whichever), you want to fetch all your referred Professor entire POJOs altogether with your University entity in a unique batch operation from the datastore, you can add **@Load** annotation in your University entity. See more [here](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities#load).

Comment: Hmm regarding your first two paragraphs, if the professors were unique (I.e professorX belongs to Harvard and only Harvard) then would it be an acceptable way?   The reason I want to know is because say for each school I have 20 professors and for each professors I have a list of 30 Students (which for this, assume are unique to the professor). Instead of calling the data store 601 (30 * 20 + 1) times I would only have to call it once, for the university which I believe is a lot cheaper.   Again I am really new to objectify and GAE so if any of my assumptions are wrong, please correct them!

Comment: Well, to be stored in the datastore professor and student are to be defined as entities; so retrieving them one way or the other should involve the same pricing

Answer (score 0):

`private List<Professor> professors;` embeds the professor data in the university. In RDBMS-land, it denormalizes the data. There is no separate and independent Professor entity.

`private List<Ref<Professor>> professors;` stores links (at the low level, `Key`s) to separate and independent Professor entities. You can add a `@Load` annotation if you want Objectify to always batch-fetch the professors when you fetch the university.

Basically `Ref<?>` is just `Key<?>` with a little more behavior. Do you want links or do you want data embedded in a larger document?